# There was already an alarm for this Intent scheduled,and I want add another one

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I register a `broadcastreceiver` in `AndroidMainfest.xml`

And in my app, a function is that User can set a time and at this time the app will send a notification. I get the arguments User set ,and use `alarmManager` to set a task which will happened at the time user set.

But I find that GOOGLE API said that:

```
If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one.
```

So if I want set two or more task,the Intent will be replaced , and at end I can only get one notification,it's not the result I want.

And then I found the intent was identified by action, data, type, class, and categories,
but I can't change action(the intent's action is the intent-filter's action was registred in the AndroidMainfest.xml ),but at the time that I change the other arguments I can't even receive a broadcast.

I thought there are four ways to solve this problem,but I only made one..

1. create lots of `broadcastreceiver` and register these in
   `AndroidMainfest.xml`,and in this way I could change the intent's
   action
2. register the `broadcastreceiver` in the program ,but I didn't
       make it
3. use service + Timer class ..
4. To make two intent different without change action.

Any help will be appreciated!!

```
Intent intent = new Intent("aaa");    //there was a broadcastreceiver's intent-filter "aaa"
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("table", "计划");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Alarm.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis()+time, pi);
```

The code is in onClickListener{onClick(){}}

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not create a new pending intent and schedule it with alarm manager?  Then you have two pending intents with two separate schedules.

Comment: If you want more than one notification you must use a unique number for each: mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueID, notification);.  You have separate alarm manager schedules and separate pending intents each with their own unique extra.  When you get the extra check which one it is, and based on that set the notification ID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Broadcasting which is not letting you to set repeat alarm you can use the calendar Object and set the alarm at whatever desired time. Once the alarm gets ON, your code will run automatically and as many times you have set the alarm.
You can also take a help of the following tutorial. I am sure it will help you out somehow.

http://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/

Comment: thank you  ,but maybe you are missing the point.See the code,